# ext js drag drop dataview determine node dropped on

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, dataview

I am using ext js to drag and drop data from one dataview to another. I want to know if the drop event happened on top of an existing node or if it was just dropped in the white space of the dataview.

Here's the code for my dropTarget:

```
...
onDesktopDataViewRender: function (v) {
    var dataView = v;

    v.dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', v.el, {
        ddGroup: 'FromSearchToDesktop',
        notifyDrop: function (source, e, dropData) {

            //Want do do something like:
            //if(dropped directly on any node) {
            //    do some logic with that node
            //}
            //else {
            //    do the code below

                var recordAlreadyExists = false;

                v.store.each(function (r) {
                    if (r.data.ID == dropData.searchData.ID) {
                        recordAlreadyExists = true;
                    }
                });

                if (recordAlreadyExists == false) {                        
                    v.store.add(dropData.searchData);
                }
            //end else

        }
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!  Finally figured this one out.

The quick answer is to create a DropZone for the node.  The long answer is how to do that.

In my program, the user can drag items from DataView A to DataView B.  After dropping the item in DataView B, the item appears in DataView B.  On top of that, the user can drag an item from DataView A, and drop it on a node inside DataView B.  The code needs to differentiate between the item being dropped on the DataView and the item being dropped on a node inside the DataView.

Generic instructions:

1. In DataViewB's onrender event, create a dropTarget with a ddGroup of
   "DataViewB"
2. Inside the notifyDrop function, create a new node.
3. Also inside the notifyDrop function,  create another dropTarget
   (this one for the node instead of the DataView) with a ddGroup of "DataViewBNode".
4. Inside DataViewA's onRender event, create a DragZone with a ddGroup
   of "DataViewBNode" (!important!)
5. Inside of DataViewA's afterrender event, add the dragZone to the
   "DataViewB" group.

Now you will be able to drag from DataViewA and drop in the white space of DataViewB to add a node, but you will also be able to drop directly on a node from DataViewB and do a different action.

**It's very important that the first ddGroup is for the node, and the one that's added in the afterrender event is for the DataView**

Here is the code for DataView A:

```
onDataViewARender: function (v) {
    var dataView = v;
...
    v.dragZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DragZone', v.getEl(), {
        ddGroup: 'DataViewBNode',   
        getDragData: function (e) {
            var sourceEl = e.getTarget(v.itemSelector, 10), d;
            if (sourceEl) {
                d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                d.id = Ext.id();
                return v.dragData = {
                    sourceEl: sourceEl,
                    repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
                    ddel: d,
                    searchData: v.getRecord(sourceEl).data,
                    store: v.store,
                    source: 'DataViewA'
                }
            }
        },

        getRepairXY: function () {
            return this.dragData.repairXY;
        }
    });
},

onDataViewAAfterRender: function(v) {
    var dragZone = v.dragZone;

    dragZone.addToGroup('DataViewB');
},
```

Here is the code for DataViewB

```
    onDataViewBRender: function (v) {
        var dataView = v;

        v.dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', v.el, {
            ddGroup: 'DataViewB',
            notifyDrop: function (source, e, dropData) {
                var recordAlreadyExists = false;

                v.store.each(function (r) {
                    if (r.data.ID == dropData.searchData.ID && r.data.Type == dropData.searchData.Type) {
                        recordAlreadyExists = true;
                    }
                });

                if (recordAlreadyExists == false) {                        
                    v.store.add(dropData.searchData);

                    var nodes = v.container.dom.childNodes[0].childNodes;
                    var index = v.container.dom.childNodes[0].childNodes.length -1;

                    //
                    //Here is where you create the dropTarget for the new node
                    //
                    nodes[index].dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', nodes[index], {
                        ddGroup: 'DataViewBNode',
                        notifyDrop: function (source, e, dropData) {
                            console.log('success')                            
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
...
    },
```